# Data will not display in textbox using StringBuilder C#

Tags: c#

Anyone with some C# experience that could help would be greatly appreciated. When I debug the code it shows that my data access function is indeed pulling the correct data, but it just will not display in my text box. FYI this is a multi-line text box so I am trying to start a new line after each item. My functions are below:

```
public class BuildersFirstSource
{
    public string sPlant { get; set; }
    public string sItem { get; set; }
    public string sCustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string sDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime dtInvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public decimal dUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal dQuantityBuilt { get; set; }
    public decimal dTotalPrice { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(sPlant).Append(",");
        sb.Append(sItem).Append(",");
        sb.Append(sCustomerNumber).Append(",");
        sb.Append(sDescription).Append(",");
        sb.Append(dtInvoiceDate).Append(",");
        sb.Append(dUnitPrice).Append(",");
        sb.Append(dQuantityBuilt).Append(",");
        sb.Append(dTotalPrice).Append(",");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sMessage = "";
    List<BuildersFirstSource> lstBuilders = new List<BuildersFirstSource>();
    BuildersFirstSource builder = new BuildersFirstSource();

    if (DataAccess.GetPriceOne(lstBuilders, out sMessage) == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    FillPriceData(lstBuilders);
}

private void FillPriceData(List<BuildersFirstSource> lstBuilders)
{
    StringBuilder sHTML = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (BuildersFirstSource item in lstBuilders)
    {
        sHTML.Append(lstBuilders);
        sHTML.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    //txtPriceOne.Text = sHTML.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? The code you posted has the line that sets the textbox control commented out. What's up with that?

Comment: remove the commented code

Comment: ``sHTML.Append(Environment.NewLine);`` there is an ``AppendLine ``function that automatically adds the new line.

Comment: Seems like you'd want to append the `item` in the loop, not the list.

Comment: Yeah there is a lot wrong here.

Comment: This a roast session but I am grateful for the feedback. I am still a junior dev and learning.

Comment: One liner: `txtPriceOne.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lstBuilders);` (Assuming `BuildersFirstSource` has a `ToString()` and .Net4).

Comment: I have edited the question and put my BuildersFirstSource class in there so you could better see what's going on with the code.

Comment: @AndrewReese Put a break-point on the line `txtPriceOne.Text = sHTML.ToString();` (assuming you've uncommented it). What is the value of `sHTML` there?

Comment: OP unresponsive to questions. Hasn't marked any answer as being helpful. Gawd, I hate helping newbies. Voting to close...

Comment: I marked both answers as helpful but since I don't have a reputation of 15 it won't show it publicly. I appreciate all of the feedback I did some tweaking and the code works. Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: @JonathanWood This was my first question I ever asked on Stack Overflow. I wasn't able to upvote or accept as answer because I didn't have enough reputation. Now I do. I just upvoted your answer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show what `BuildersFirstSource` is exactly, and the line that populates your `TextBox` control is commented out, but shouldn't your code look more like this?

```
StringBuilder sHTML = new StringBuilder();

foreach (BuildersFirstSource item in lstBuilders)
{
    // Modify the following line so that you are adding the
    // correct string from item
    sHTML.AppendLine(item.ToString());
}
txtPriceOne.Text = sHTML.ToString();
```

Comment: @maccettura: True. I've changed that, although it isn't specific to the problem.

Comment: I feel like your solution should work but for some reason it is not. BuildersFirstSource looks like:

Comment: @AndrewReese: I'm not sure what your association is with @Neil, but it does work if you understand it. What are you passing--exactly--to `sHTML.AppendLine`? Can you use the debugger (you should learn if not)? What is the string being added on each iteration?

Comment: I just edited my question and put my class BuildersFirstSouce so it would better explain what's going on with my code. I have the debugger going and lstBuilders is being filled with correct data, but it doesn't show up in the text box.

Comment: @AndrewReese: I don't think you answered my question. What are you passing--exactly--to `sHTML.AppendLine)`? This should be very easy. Can you set a breakpoint on that line? What does the resulting string look like? What is getting added? Looking at the code you added, it should work as I have it. But you've given me nothing about the other questions I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be adding the whole list of items to the string builder for each item in the lstBuilders collection.  You should be adding the field you are interested in displaying:

```
foreach (BuildersFirstSource item in lstBuilders)
{
    sHTML.AppendLine(item.TheFieldYouAreInterestedIn.ToString());
}
txtPriceOne.Text = sHTML.ToString();
```